# select min on group

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

I have a moderately complex query to run which I have somewhat simplified below for purpose of this question. I have 2 tables;

```
TABLE: plan_costs
id,   plan_id,   cost,    special_cost   + more columns....
1     1          23.00    12.00
2     1          25.00    15.00
3     2          5.00     2.00
4     2          45.00    28.00
5     3          35.00    30.00
6     3          65.00    60.00

TABLE: plan_details
plan_id,   group_id,    + more columns....
1          1
2          1
3          2
```

What I need is a list of the cheapest plans, between 2 values (in this case 5 and 30) but only one plan per group. When I run the plan below I get one plan per group, but it is not always the cheapest one. Note: There is a case condition that uses special_cost in preference to cost if it is not 0. Any ideas?

```
SELECT p1.id,
       p2.plan_id,
       p1.cost,
       p1.special_cost CASE
                           WHEN p1.special_cost = 0 THEN MIN(p1.cost)
                           ELSE MIN(p1.special_cost)
                       END AS cost_order,
FROM plan_costs AS p1
LEFT JOIN plan_details AS p2 ON (p2.plan_id = p1.plan_id)
WHERE CASE
          WHEN p1.special_cost = 0 THEN p1.cost >= 5
          ELSE p1.special_cost >= 5
      END
  AND CASE
          WHEN p1.special_cost = 0 THEN p1.cost <= 30
          ELSE p1.special_cost <= 30
      END
GROUP BY p2.group_id
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN p1.special_cost = 0 THEN p1.cost
             ELSE p1.special_cost
         END ASC
```

EDIT: added final result i need

REQUIRED RESULT:

```
id,   plan_id,   cost,    special_cost
1     1          23.00    12.00
5     3          35.00    30.00
```

Comment: What is the desired result for the sample data you posted?

Comment: Would special_cost be less than cost ever?

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal I will be outputting a list of the results in html.

Comment: @Vaibhav Desai special_cost will always be less than cost but if special_cost is 0, then i want to use cost

Comment: Why not set the default value of special_cost to the value of cost. That will reduce the complexity of the qyery.

Comment: I still need both the special_cost and cost in the results, i will edit the question to show this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   a.group_id, 
   pc.plan_id,
   a.minCost
FROM
   (SELECT 
      pd.group_id,
      min(if(pc.special_cost = 0, pc.cost, pc.special_cost)) as minCost 
   FROM
      plan_costs pc
   INNER JOIN
      plan_details pd
   ON 
      pd.plan_id = pc.plan_id
   GROUP BY 
      pd.group_id) a
INNER JOIN
   plan_details pd
ON   
   pd.group_id = a.group_id
INNER JOIN
   plan_costs pc
ON
   pc.plan_id = a.plan_id AND 
   if(pc.special_cost = 0, pc.cost, pc.special_cost) = a.minCost
```

MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so in our case the `plan_id` were different so we could not take advantage of this feature so we had to make extra joins to get the desired result...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks @Meherzad, is b.plan_id a typo and meant to be a.plan_id